MoveIt! "Jupyter Notebook Prototyping" tutorial : cannot configure planning scene monitor
I am doing the MoveIt! tutorial Jupyter Notebook Prototyping, but I cannot instantiate the MoveItPy object, because of an impossibility to configure the planning scene monitor.
However, the Moveit configuration dictionary seems to include the proper definition of the planning scene monitor.
For more details, I work on a VMWare virtual machine with Ubuntu and ROS2 Rolling. The .launch.py, the .yaml configurations, the .py executable nodes and the .urdf.xacro files, which I have inspected, are those from the tutorial's GitHub and their contents look consistent.
Firstly, after sourcing I launched in a terminal jupyter_notebook_prototyping.launch.py. It opened the notebook as expected. Then, the line  panda = MoveItPy(node_name="moveit_py", config_dict=moveit_config) caused the error RuntimeError: Unable to configure planning scene monitor.
Yet, moveit_config includes what seems to be the proper definition for the planning scene monitor : 
'planning_scene_monitor_options': {'name': 'planning_scene_monitor', 'robot_description': 'robot_description', 'joint_state_topic': '/joint_states', 'attached_collision_object_topic': '/moveit_cpp/planning_scene_monitor', 'publish_planning_scene_topic': '/moveit_cpp/publish_planning_scene', 'monitored_planning_scene_topic': '/moveit_cpp/monitored_planning_scene', 'wait_for_initial_state_timeout': 10.0}
Has anyone an explanation and know how to solve that?
Thank you a lot in advance!
